# make a floating text box with button that saves all text in text box to as a .txt file multiple lines and save files named by time created as title

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a floating text box with button that saves all text in text box to as a .txt file multiple lines and saves files named by time created as title and in folders created by month.

I would like the file name to be automated by the time it was created like this [9-21-19_3_00_am]

I so far got a button that calls another button that will save anything i write in that second window into a .txt file. it saves everything i write though as the file name not like a title or prompting me to name the file name and adding all text written as the body of .txt file

---

I wanted this to be able to store entries and organize them some way as the .txt files are created

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename

win = tk.Tk()

HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 800

canvas = tk.Canvas( height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()
#

def send():
    print("button clicked:")

def f():
    def save():
        a = t.get()
        with open((a + '.txt'), 'w') as f:
            f.write(a)

    top = tk.Tk()
    t = tk.StringVar(top)
    tk.Entry(top, textvariable=t).pack()
    tk.Button(top, text = 'Save as a file', command=save).pack()



win.configure(background="#808000")

frame1 = tk.Frame(win,width=1100, height=776,bg = '#ffffff',
                  borderwidth=1, relief="sunken")
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame1)
editArea = tk.Text(frame1, width=400, height=400, wrap="word",
                   yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,
                   borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
scrollbar.config(command=editArea.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
editArea.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
frame1.place(x=1.0,y=1.0)

send = tk.Button(frame1,text="send", command=f)
send.place(relx=0.1, relwidth=0.1, relheight=0.1)



win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you write shorted senteces ? And you could add example - what filename do you expect ?

Comment: you can use `datetime.datetime.now()` to get current time and then you can use .strftime(...)` to format it. You would have to use `os.makedirs()` to create directory

Comment: Thank for reply, I want the  filename to be generated from the date and time, i also want the .txt or.doc file to be placed in folders  inside of directory in this sussession year/month/my_text_file_with_date_and_imput_text_from_frame1.txt